# Passing a value from controller to directive AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to pass a value from the controller to the directive but the directive in the view can be overridden.

Example Controller

```
    var controllers = angular.module('Project.Controllers.ActionBarCtrl', []);
    controllers.controller('ActionBarCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope', 
        function($scope, $rootScope){
        $scope.buttonColor = 'red' 
}]);
```

Then in my view there are two possible ways to load

```
<div my-button button-color='green'></div>
```

or

```
<div my-button></div>
```

in the directive i want to pass in the button color (green in the first div and the default of red in the second div), here is my directive

```
sharedDirectives.directive('myButton', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            'buttonColor': '@'
        },
        template: '<div>' +
                    '<button class="uifw-frm-button small {{buttonColor}}" ng-click="showHideInner()">
                 + </div>
```

I can get it to work with the first div and populating the buttonColor property with the value of green but when i leave it out and want to return red I get the value as undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
template: '<div>' +
            '<button class="uifw-frm-button small" ng-class="{'red':!buttonColor,buttonColor:buttonColor}" ng-click="showHideInner()">
         + </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add the compile function to your directive:

```
compile: function(element, attrs)
{
   if (!attrs.buttonColor) { attrs.buttonColor= 'red'; }
}
```

<strike>or in the controller of the directive:</strike>

```
controller: function($scope){
    $scope.buttonColor = $scope.buttonColor || 'red';
  }
```

ok, the one with compile works:

http://jsfiddle.net/eYJqC/

Comment: Thanks for this answer, i gave it a try however more functionality was needed after the button click and the 'compile: ...' stoped any further code from executing. So the answer that i used is the one I chose above. I dont know what if i was doing something wrong after the compile, but this didnt allow for any other code to run.